# How do I get VS Code to get access to .NET, after I installed .NET?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework

As of now, the terminal in VS Code doesn't recognize `dotnet` command, as shown in the image below. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: hey, refer this article may it help you.https://medium.com/danielpadua/vscode-asp-net-core-setup-development-environment-d4790d89e422